# SQL Server with Pacemaker on Ubuntu 18.04, 'Resource must be configured with notify=true'

Tags: sql-server, high-availability, pacemaker

I am trying to configure Pacemaker on 3 Ubuntu machines and I am following [Microsoft's instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/fr-ca/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-availability-group-cluster-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver15)

When done with all the cluster node are blocked and non of the resource is starting. The error I can read from corosync.log is:

> Resource must be configured with notify=true

**pcs status:**

```
Cluster name: ag_cluster
Stack: corosync
Current DC: serv-01 (version 1.1.18-2b07d5c5a9) - partition with quorum
Last updated: Wed Apr 29 11:29:03 2020
Last change: Wed Apr 29 09:51:23 2020 by root via crm_resource on serv-01

3 nodes configured
4 resources configured

Online: [ serv-01 serv-02 serv-03 ]

Full list of resources:

 Master/Slave Set: ag_cluster-master [ag_cluster]
     ag_cluster (ocf::mssql:ag):        FAILED serv-01 (blocked)
     ag_cluster (ocf::mssql:ag):        FAILED serv-02 (blocked)
     ag_cluster (ocf::mssql:ag):        FAILED serv-03 (blocked)
 virtualip      (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Stopped

Failed Actions:
* ag_cluster_stop_0 on serv-01 'not configured' (6): call=33, status=complete, exitreason='Resource must be configured with notify=true',
    last-rc-change='Wed Apr 29 09:50:16 2020', queued=0ms, exec=64ms
* ag_cluster_stop_0 on serv-02 'not configured' (6): call=30, status=complete, exitreason='Resource must be configured with notify=true',
    last-rc-change='Wed Apr 29 09:50:16 2020', queued=0ms, exec=73ms
* ag_cluster_stop_0 on serv-03 'not configured' (6): call=30, status=complete, exitreason='Resource must be configured with notify=true',
    last-rc-change='Wed Apr 29 09:50:16 2020', queued=0ms, exec=68ms


Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/enabled
  pacemaker: active/enabled
  pcsd: active/enabled
```

This cmd was run and the resource is configured as described:

```
sudo pcs resource create ag_cluster ocf:mssql:ag ag_name=ag1 meta failure-timeout=30s --master meta notify=true
```

Answer (score 1):

pcs resource create ag_cluster ocf:mssql:ag ag_name=my_ag1 meta failure-timeout=30s master notify=true

remove the -- before master.  Microsoft f'ed up their documentation :)

Answer (score -1):

@Greg Thanks for reaching out.
Nothing has change after I have recreated the entire cluster and have run the updated command be excluding(--) master. 
The log says it all:

[image]
The current cluster status looks like:

[image]